# What is a better virtue to ask for than self-control?

Tags: prayer

Self-control, even though it is praised in the Bible as something wonderful, and even though Proverbs warns of the consequences of **not** having it (Proverbs 25:28) looks less and less like a foundation to build one's life. There are two things going against it:

1. Unlike Justice, Courage, and Wisdom, Self-Control is a contingent virtue: it is contingent on there being something bad in you that needs to be controlled in the first place. If there were nothing bad inside of you, self-control would not be a virtue at all. But that is illogical: why not ask, then, for that bad thing to be destroyed rather than for the grace to control it?
2. Self-control, when taken to its logical conclusion... doesn't get you very much. Let's suppose someone asks God for superabundant self-control and He gives it to him. What does he get? Rather, let's look at what he **doesn't** get. First of all, he doesn't get any new talents: an average person with superabundant self-control is still average. He doesn't get a better personality. And from a utilitarian perspective, he gets an improved ability to advance the welfare of others to the extent that he can force himself to work ("willpower"). Therefore, the end result of self-control is decency: the person is now decent, and that is not good enough.

What is a better virtue to ask God for that will empower one's being?

Comment: The apostle James seems to disagree with you _He that bridleth not his tongue, that man's religion is in vain._ James 1:26. If one does not control one's members, one's religion is seen to be just a pretence.

Comment: @NigelJ Good point

Comment: @NigelJ But consider this quote from Catherine of Siena: "Be silent no more! Cry out with one hundred thousand tongues. I see that, because of this silence, the world is in ruins, the Spouse of Christ has grown pale; the color is taken from her face because her blood has been sucked out, that is the blood of Christ, which is given as a free gift and not by right." She was a saint and doctor of the church. There's a greater risk in not speaking than speaking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest Faith. That is, believing in and trusting in God. Accordng to Hebrews, this necessarily precedes any other virtues;

"Without faith, it is impossible to please him. For whoever would draw near to God must believe that he exists and that he rewards those who seek him" (Hebrews ch11 v6, RSV).

That "must" is psychological. Nobody will even try to please him unless they first believe both these things.